# Do class fields within an LMAX Disruptor event need to be volatile?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

Sample code from the LMAX Disruptor "Getting Started"...

```
public class LongEvent
{
    private long value;

    public void set(long value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/wiki/Getting-Started

Why isn't `private long value` declared as `volatile`?

I ask because, implicit to the Disruptor pattern, data is shared between threads (producer -> consumer).

My guess: There is already (at least) one memory fence between the producer and consumer threads.

Comment: A reasonable guess given it would be interesting if Distruptor could be implemented without any fences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Peter's comment gives a good clue, and in fact, yes there are memory fences involved.

You can see a putOrderedLong() compareAndSet() and so on are used in the Sequence class. Each of these enforce memory ordering.

See the [source code](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/lmax/disruptor/Sequence.java) for more details.